# How to connect to internet using browser provided in emulators of Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded Android SDK emulator, but I am not able to connect to the internet in the stock browser provided in the emulator. My system is connected to the internet, but I would like to test the same in browser of the emulator.

Please let me know if I need to change any setting.

Comment: @fargath I think he means stock browser.

Comment: @Audrius Sorry just misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 0):

In emulator go to Settings -> Wireless and Network -> Mobile Network

Then enable the Data Enabled option so that u can use the internet